# Data selecting in data science project about predicting house prices

Tags: data-science, prediction

This is my first data science project and I need to select some data. Of course, I know that I can not just select all the data available because this will result in overfitting. I am currently investigating house prices in the capital of Denmark for the past 10 years and I wanted to know which type of houses I should select in my data:

1. Owner-occupied flats and houses (This gives a dataset of 50000 elements)
2. Or just owner-occupied flats (this gives a dataset of 43000 elements)

So as you can see there are a lot more owner-occupied flats sold in the capital of Denmark. My opinion is that I should select just the owner-occupied flats because then I have the "same" kind of elements in my data and still have 43000 elements.

Also, there are a lot higher taxes involved if you own a house rather than owning an owner-occupied flat. This might affect the price of the house and skew the data a little bit.

I have seen a few projects where both owner-occupied flats and houses are selected for the data and the conclusion was overfitting, so that is what I am looking to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

This is an classic example of over-fitting due to lack of data or insufficient data.

Let me example the selection process to resolve this kind of problem. I will example using the example of credit card fraud then relate that with your question or any future problem of prediction with classified data.

In ideal world credit card fraud are not that common. So, if you look at the real data you will find only 2% data which resulted in fraud. So, if you train a model with this datasets it would be biased as you don't have normal distribution of the class (i.e fraud and none fraud transaction in your case its Owner-occupied flats and houses). There are ***4 a way to tackle this issue***.

Let's Suppose Datasets has 90 none fraud data points and 10 fraud data points.

### 1. Under sampling majority class

---

In this we just select 10 data points from 90 and train model with 10:10 so distribution is normalised (In your case using only 7000 of 43000 flats). This is not ideal way as we would be throughout a huge amount of data.

### 2. Over sampling minority class by duplication

---

In this we duplicate the 10 data points to make it 90 data point distribution is normalised (In your case duplicating 7000 house data to make it 43000 i.e equal to that of flat). While this work there is a better way.

### 3. Over sampling minority class by SMOTE (recommended)

---

Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique is a technique we use k nearest neigbors algo to generate the minority class in your case the housing data. There is module named imbalanced-learn ([here](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/)) which can be use to implement this.

### 4. Ensemble Method

---

In this method you divide your data into multiple datasets to make it balance for example dividing 90 into 9 sets so that each set can have 10 fraud class data and 10 none fraud class data. In your case diving 43000 in batch of 7000. After that training each one separately and using majority vote mechanism to predict.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer. I wanted to know how good these methods are in real life? And is it a common practice in the data science community to do this? Should I do this before og after feature selection?

Comment: SMOTE is the only recommended method and it is standard practice in solving this issue.   This should be before feature process as data might affect your feature.

Comment: @restingquartH I am not able to comment on last ans so asking here is this distribution about the predicted price or default dataset ?

Comment: The graph is the default dataset. It shows the house prices and owner-occupied flat prices for the past 30 years. If you look over the graph there is at most a 12% deviation between the two prices in 2006 and 2018.  Is this deviation enough to say that the data is biased/insufficient data?

Answer (score 0):

So now I have created the following diagram. The green line shows the price per square meter of owner occupied flats and the red line shows price per square meter of houses (all prices in DKK). I was wondering if there is imbalanced classification? The maximum deviation of the prices is atmost 10% (see for example 2018). Is 10% enough to say that the data is biased and hence therefore is imbalanced classified?

[image]